# Scheduling Daily Tasks at a Specific Time in macOS using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a swiftUI, macOS app. I am building an internal app which will be on our mac computers in our company warehouse. A feature of this app is going to be, every morning at 5am, we want to fetch an api service and print the pdfs we get back.

I have everything working as intended with a timer in swift, But the timer doesn't account for the mac being "Asleep". This code is going to fire every 24 hours from 5am.
But over night when the mac is asleep, my timer stops and only keeps running when mac is awake.

Code:

```
/// Call this function to refresh everyday at 5am
    func initiatePdfsUpdate() {

        /// set the time we want our code to be ran.
        let dateComponents = DateComponents(hour: 5, minute: 0)
        /// set current date = start of a new day. EX: 12:00 AM(midnight)
        let currentDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        /// sets the fire date = current data(midnight) + date componets hours and minutes
        let fireDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: currentDate)!

        let secondsIn24Hrs = 86400.0

        let timer = Timer(
            fireAt: fireDate,
            interval: secondsIn24Hrs,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(fetchAndPrintDocs),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        )

        // Add the timer to the main run loop
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
```

Next, I learned about NSWorkSpace notification Center.

In my app delegate class, I have this code to detect when the computer 'wakes up'.

code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, LoggerProtocol {

    let logger = Logger(subsystem: Constants.AppInfo.loggerSubSystem, category: "AppDelegate")

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.logger.log("App did finish launching")

        registerForWakeNotifications()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.logger.log("Application will terminate")

    }

    func registerForWakeNotifications() {
        let notificationCenter = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
        
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willSleep), name: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didWake), name: NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification, object: nil)
    }
   
    @objc
    private func willSleep() {
        self.logger.log("Application will Sleep")

    }

    @objc
    private func didWake() {
        // Should i initiate the call here 

        self.logger.log("Application did wake")
    }
}
```

This is working as expected for me, but obviously if our warehouse team awakens the mac at 8am, thats when the code will run.

Is there a better way to do this and have it run at 5am no matter the mac status? The app should stay open on the mac all day and all night.

Comment: The issue here is that you're doing the scheduling yourself, in your own app. As you noticed, this only works when your app is running (and necessarily, the mac is on to run it). Instead, you should outsource this job to launchd, which can schedule your job for you. This article seems like a good start: https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-launchd-run-scripts-on-schedule-macos/